# Date.parse("Nov-12-2015 12:41 PM") is null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to parse this Date.parse("Nov-12-2015 12:41 PM") and it returns a null. It works for all other times but fails for 12:00 PM through 12:59 PM

Comment: I can't reproduce that in latest stable Chrome. Both return a number.

Comment: I can't reproduce it too, here is fiddle which is working: http://jsfiddle.net/wxq4c58d/

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: same here, do you have any context for this call?

Comment: It works very oddly in Edge - there is return value  -125727164340000

Comment: After some debugging, I am finding that my project is using a date.js file from http://www.datejs.com, the parse function in this file is failing.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe solution for you, it is called Moment.JS and everytime when i have problem with time in Javascript this solve the problem.

Here is link [http://momentjs.com/](http://Moment.JS)

Example with moment here:

```
moment("Nov-12-2015 12:41 PM").unix()
```